# How to quickly update a running docker-compose container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do you quickly update one running service using docker-compose.

I find myself often running `docker-compose stop SERVICE`, `docker-compose build SERVICE` and `docker-compose up -d SERVICE`.

Is there an easier way, preferably with little down time.

Comment: How did you solve your issue eventually?

Answer (score 10):

In dev environment I would suggest you to create a volume mapped to your source code tree and setup hot reload.

For production there is an [article](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/#/deploying-changes) suggesting the next command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build --no-deps -d SERVICE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're having to restart it to pickup code changes you could try using a `volume`.

Otherwise the commands you are running are the fastest option.  If `stop` is taking 10 seconds see https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#why-do-my-services-take-10-seconds-to-stop, or consider using `docker-compose kill SERVICE` to force shutdown.